# Tangent to the circle concentric with the circle, $2x^2+2y^2-6x-10y=183$

Tags: circles, tangent-line

> Let $C$ be the circle concentric with the circle, $2x^2+2y^2-6x-10y=183$ and having area $(1/10)th$ of the area of this circle. Then a tangent to $C$, parallel to the line, $3x+y=0$ makes an intercept on the $y$-axis, which is equal to

The given circle is $x^2+y^2-3x-5y-\frac{183}{2}=0$. So, the center is $(\frac32,\frac52)$. And the radius is $10$. Let the radius of $C$ be $r$, so, $$\pi r^2=\frac1{10}\pi(10)^2\implies r^2=10$$ So, the equation of $C$ becomes $$(x-\frac32)^2+(y-\frac52)^2=10$$

Taking derivative, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x-\frac32}{3(y-\frac52)}=-3$$

Putting the value of $(x-\frac32)$ in the equation of $C$, I get $y=\frac{215}{82}$. From that, I get $x=\frac{33}{82}$. Thus, the equation of the tangent becomes $$y-\frac{215}{82}=-3(x-\frac{33}{82})$$

Putting $x=0$, I get the $y-$intercept as $\frac{314}{82}$. But the answer is given as $17$.

What is my mistake? Also, is there a quicker way to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: There always are two tangents to a given circle parallel to a given line, so there should be two answers to this question. Am I missing something?
Also, your derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ looks fishy - I think that the 3 in the denominator is wrong.

Comment: The derivative should be $2(x-\frac{3}{2})+2\frac{dy}{dx}(y-\frac52)=0$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I added an extra 3 there. Sorry. Working on it now.

Comment: Thanks all, got the answer as 17.

Comment: Not only $17$ but also $-3$ should be an [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-3%2F2%29%5E2%2B%28%28-3x-3%29-5%2F2%29%5E2%3D10).

Comment: @mathlove I think i am getting the other answer as 6. Not sure how to look for the answer in the link given by you.

Comment: Sorry, getting it as -3 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a faster method, observe that the slope of the circle’s radius at the point of tangency is $\frac13$, so the two points of tangency are $$\left(\frac32,\frac52\right)\pm \sqrt{10}\left(\frac3{\sqrt{10}},\frac1{\sqrt{10}}\right) = \left(\frac32\pm3,\frac52\pm1\right).$$ The two tangent lines are therefore $$\left(y-\frac52\pm1\right) = -3\left(x-\frac32\pm3\right)$$ with $y$-intercepts of $-3$ and $17$.

As for where your calculations went wrong, it looks like you made a sign error when you computed the derivative. From the original equation of the circle, we have $$4x+4yy'-6-10y' = (4y-10)y'+(4x-6) = 0,$$ so $$y' = -{2x-3\over2y-5}$$ and $$x-\frac32 = \frac32(2y-5) = 3y-\frac{15}2.$$ You probably forgot to negate the terms that don’t involve $y'$ when you moved them to the other side of the equation while solving for $y'$.

Answer (score 1):

Another, rather artificial approach: we intersect the line $y=-3x+a$ with the circle $\left(x-\frac32\right)^2+\left(y-\frac52\right)=10$ simply plugging $y=-3x+a$ into the equation, got quadratic and the discriminant should be $0$ for having exactly $1$ solution. Hence [$a^2-14a-51=0$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-3%2F2%29%5E2%2B%28-3*x%2Ba-5%2F2%29%5E2%3D10) hence $a=7\pm 10$.